# My scrollView cut my last picture Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, swift3

I have an horizontal scrollView, where I add my array of image, but it alway cut the picture, my content mode is scaleToFill. I printed the size of my imageView and my scrollView and gave me the same size, so why can't I see my picture filling all my scrollView

[My first Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TChIO.png)  and
[My last image of my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEdlK.png)

Here is my code

```
func getFavoriteSalon()
{
    arrayOfDataScrollView = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "large"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Kristoff-image-kristoff-36081750-500-266"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image-battle-for-dream-island-39780938-500-266")]
    mainScrollView.contentSize.width = (mainScrollView.frame.width) * CGFloat(arrayOfDataScrollView.count)

    for i in 0..<arrayOfDataScrollView.count
    {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        let xPosition = self.mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width , height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)
        imageView.image = arrayOfDataScrollView[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        print(self.mainScrollView.frame.width) =>Give me 375
        print(self.mainScrollView.frame.height) =>Give me 200
        print("Width => \(imageView.frame.width)") =>Give me 375
        print("height => \(imageView.frame.height)") =>Give me 200
        mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like your contentSize is not set to the size of your images all put together side by side. Add up their widths, and adjust the mainScrollView.contentSize.width to be that value.

Comment: My content size have 1125 of width I got same size for the total of  my tree image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, for me it's a bug xcode, i work with an emulateur of Iphone7+, but I got the value of an Iphone 7 when i print my variables, Be sure to have the preview, and the emulateur looking the same device

Answer (score 0):

Use this and set content size according image

```
            var xPosition:CGFloat = 0
            for i in 0..<arrayOfDataScrollView.count{
            var frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)
            frame.origin.x = CGFloat(xPosition)
            frame.size = mainScrollView.frame.size
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            imageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
            imageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
            imageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition
            imageView.frame.origin.y = 0
            mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            xPosition  +=  imageView.frame.size.width + 5; (5 you can change this value)
            mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(i) * imageView.frame.size.width, height:
                mainScrollView.frame.size.height)

          }
```

Comment: What is imageWidth and imageHeight ? I can't put static number I guess,
when I tried nothing displayed. When I print my mainScroll.contentSize, I have a 1125 for my width, and the total of my 3 picture  equal this size (375 * 3)

Comment: imageWidth = yourscrollview.frame.size.width and imageHeight  = yourscrollview.frame.size.heigth you can take your custom width

Comment: Oh I fond why he doesn't display in your code I forgot to add my line for add my image in the imageView, now he display the images, but they still don't take all the scrollView